How can I configure Angular 17 dev server to redirect HTTP to HTTPS?
I've configured the Angular dev server to use HTTPS with SSL successfully:
"port": 4200,
"ssl": true,
"sslKey": "./tools/.ssl/localhost+2-key.pem",
"sslCert": "./tools/.ssl/localhost+2.pem"

When I navigate to https://localhost:4200, the page loads correctly. However, when I navigate to http://localhost:4200, I receive a 404 error. How can I configure the Angular 17 dev server to redirect HTTP to HTTPS? Is it possible to achieve this within Angular, or do I need to use a script tag for the redirection?

U have to use a proxy and modify your package.json start script to use the proxy configuration:"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"

I always ignore ssl on localhost.
